# nodejs process.on('uncaughtException') not working?

Tags: node.js

when I add `process.on('uncaughtException')`, it will catch an error such as doing `nonExistingFunction();`, but my application crashes once in a while with the error:

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

Any help please?
P.S. I'm using express with socket.io

Comment: Can you show full error message?

Comment: Sometimes it only shows that, and sometimes I can see Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:544:26)

Comment: We're having the same problem (uncatchable `ECONNRESET`) over here: https://github.com/request/request/issues/2161#issuecomment-313375694 Seems like it's a bug in a core component/module of nodejs